# how I can arrange the object on the stage AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a puzzle and 9 pictures, so when I Start Drag any picture i want it to come above of the all remaining.

How I can do it on Action Script 3.0?
this is for example:

```
import flash.events.Event;

Puz3_Level7A.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, StartPuz3);
function StartPuz3 (e:Event):void
{
    Puz3_Level7A.startDrag();
}
Puz2_Level7A.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, StartPuz2);
function StartPuz2 (e:Event):void
{
    Puz2_Level7A.startDrag();
}
Puz1_Level7A.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, StartPuz1);
function StartPuz1 (e:Event):void
{
    Puz1_Level7A.startDrag();
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I mean on AS3 Action script 3.0

Comment: I'm sorry this is the first question I have , so I don't know all the role

Comment: You should read up on how the Displaylist works, [here for example](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3displaylist/) The easiest way is to put your desired sprite at the very end of the Displaylist. For example using [swapchildren()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#swapChildren())

Comment: Ok But How I can use it with startDrag and StopDrag?

Comment: Well, when would it make sense? Every time before you call startdrag on a Sprite, swap that Sprite in the displaylist so that it gets put on top.

Comment: @KidsCare - please comment if you are having any further issues or if none of the answers helped you resolve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try following.

```
import flash.events.Event;

Puz3_Level7A.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, StartPuz3);
function StartPuz3 (e:Event):void
{
    this.setChildIndex(Puz3_Level7A, this.numChildren - 1);
    Puz3_Level7A.startDrag();
}
Puz2_Level7A.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, StartPuz2);
function StartPuz2 (e:Event):void
{
    this.setChildIndex(Puz2_Level7A, this.numChildren - 1);
    Puz2_Level7A.startDrag();
}
Puz1_Level7A.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, StartPuz1);
function StartPuz1 (e:Event):void
{
    this.setChildIndex(Puz1_Level7A, this.numChildren - 1);
    Puz1_Level7A.startDrag();
}
```

This code assume all the above sprites are children of same sprite.

Comment: Friendly tip, you should learn about the `event.currentTarget` property. It would make this code much more concise.   You could have just one event handler for all objects that way.

Comment: There could be better way, AS3 have hell of approaches :)  @aaron already suggested a neat way. I just explained the problem OP have in code.

Answer (score 1):

you can just do

```
this.parent.addChild(this);
```

to put 'this' on the top of all parent's children

Answer (score -1):

There are some perfectly good answers already, but in the interest of DRY (don't repeat yourself) and completeness, here is my take on this.

A clean way of doing this, including stopping the drag.  No inline functions or unnecessarily repeated code.

```
//add the mouse down listener to all objects you want to be able to drag.
//if you have a lot, you could also do this in a loop to make it more concise.
Puz3_Level7A.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragPuzzlePiece, false, 0, true);
Puz2_Level7A.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragPuzzlePiece, false, 0, true);
Puz1_Level7A.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragPuzzlePiece, false, 0, true);

var currentPiece:Sprite; //a var to hold a reference to item last mouse downed (to use in the mouse up handler)

//the mouse down handler to drag a piece
function dragPuzzlePiece(e:Event):void
{
    currentPiece = e.currentTarget as Sprite; //the event's current target is a reference to the item you added the listener to.  We are casting it as a Sprite so the compiler knows what kind of object it is.

    addChild(currentPiece); //this will bring it to the top. 
    //setChildIndex(currentPiece, numChildren-1); //this would do the same as above
    //swapChildren(currentPiece, getChildAt(numChildren-1); //this would do the same as above
    currentPiece.startDrag(); //start dragging the piece that was clicked

    //now listen for the mouse up event to stop dragging the piece
    //we listen on the stage, as sometimes dragging can lag when moving the mouse quickly and the mouse may not be over the item when you release the button
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler);
}

function mouseUpHandler(e:Event):void {
    //remove the mouse up listener
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler);

    //stop the drag:
    if(currentPiece) currentPiece.stopDrag();

    //do something with currentPiece now that the drag is done.
      //like make sure the piece is in a valid spot
      //check if the puzzle is complete now

    puzzleDone(); //let's say you call this function at some point
}

function puzzleDone():void {
    currentPiece = null; //clear this var so objects can be garbage collected
    //!important
    //when you use setChildIndex, or AddChild, or SwapChildren 
    //or anything that modifies the parentage of a object
    //that object will no longer be removed by timeline keyframes
    //it will stick around until it's parent is removed, or you explicitly remove it.

    //to that end, you'll want to manually remove your puzzle pieces when done
    removeChild(Puz3_Level7A);
    removeChild(Puz2_Level7A);
    removeChild(Puz1_Level7A);
    //you can use some of patterns below for this as well.

}
```

---

In regards to adding the mouse down listeners to all your puzzle pieces, here are some other options to scale better if you have a whole lot of pieces:

1. If the pieces are all FlashPro instance names, you could do this:

   ```
   //loop three times
   for(var i:int=1;i<=3;i++){
      //get the child dynamically from the name (
      var piece:DisplayObject = getChildByName("Puz" + i + "_Level7A");
      if(piece){
          piece.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragPuzzlePiece, false, 0, true); 
      }
   }
   ```
2. If your puzzle pieces are the sole children of a common parent (let's say this code is on the timeline of that parent), you could do this:

   ```
   //loop backwards through all children of this
   var i:int = this.numChildren;
   while(i--){
       this.getChildAt(i).addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragPuzzlePiece, false, 0, true);
   }
   ```
3. If you have your pieces in an array:

   ```
   var allPieces:Array = [Puz3_Level7A, Puz2_Level7A, Puz3_Level7A];

   for(var i:int=0;i<allPieces.length;i++){
       allPieces[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragPuzzlePiece, false, 0, true);
   }
   ```

Comment: Why not create a `Puzzle` class instead of this timeline code?

Comment: @Aaron - This could just as easily be class code. I would very much disagree that it's "Not Useful". –

Answer (score -2):

I upvoted @SameerJain's answer, it will do what you want. Taking it a *little* further, you can reduce all your repeated code with a simple function that makes your puzzle pieces draggable:

```
function makeDraggable(target:Sprite):void {
    target.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragStart);
}

function dragStart(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var target:Sprite = e.currentTarget as Sprite;
    target.startDrag();
    setChildIndex(target, numChildren - 1);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dragEnd);
}

function dragEnd(e:MouseEvent):void {
    stopDrag();
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dragEnd);
}

makeDraggable(Puz3_Level7A);
makeDraggable(Puz2_Level7A);
makeDraggable(Puz1_Level7A);
```